# using Bowtie to map miRNA-seq data to rfam and also reference genome

Tags: genomics, read-mapping, bowtie2, non-coding

I am using Bowtie to remove non-coding RNAs (tRNA, snRNA, rRNA) by rfam and also maping our microRNA-seq data with mirbase using following code:

```
bowtie -m 10  -l 18 -n 1 -v 2 -e 80 --best --strata -a   genome.index.file    inputfastqfile   --un unaligned.fq
```

Unfortunately I dont have any references or index for that code.
Are there any other settings and options to improve this code?

Comment: Why rfam specifically? You can you rRNA, tRNA, and snRNA database to get their sequences (assuming human genome) and use a hierarchical sequence alignment strategy to remove all the ncRNAs and, finally, map the filtered sequences to miRNAs.